# Как поставить sun-java6-jdk на Ubuntu Meerkat?

Tags: java, ubuntu

Ставлю пакет sun-java6-jdk на Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

и получаю ошибку.

*Пакет sun-java6-jdk недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого пакета.
Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел, или доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета sun-java6-jdk не найден кандидат на установку*

Какие репозитории нужно подключить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно добавить репозитории partner.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

apt-get -qq update
apt-get -y -qq install sun-java6-jdk
```

Comment: echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu maverick partner" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Отказано в доступе